# Changing table rows on dropdown select not working

Tags: jquery, html-table, onchange

I have a page to store user information divided in 4 page. What I want is to change some rows which is on 4th page on the select option located on first page. I am using jQuery to do so but currently unsuccessful. Here are my code please correct me.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlCategory').change(function () {
                if (this.value == "Others") {
                    $('#Other').show();
                } else {
                    $('#Other').hide();
                }

            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <select id="ddlCategory">
                        <option>Choose</option>
                        <option value="Value1">Value1</option>
                        <option value="Value2">Value 2</option>
                        <option value="Others">Others</option>
                    </select>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Category: " />
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr id="Other" style="display: none">
              <table>

              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                </td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>      
       </table>

             
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nested `table` sometimes make conflict in the way elements are displayed. If you put the `ID` and the `style` on the `table` itself and not on its `tr` container it will work as in the following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlCategory').change(function () {
                if (this.value == "Others") {
                    $('#Other').show();
                } else {
                    $('#Other').hide();
                }

            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <select id="ddlCategory">
                        <option>Choose</option>
                        <option value="Value1">Value1</option>
                        <option value="Value2">Value 2</option>
                        <option value="Others">Others</option>
                    </select>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Category: " />
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
              <table id="Other" style="display: none">

              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                </td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>      
       </table>

             
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks. One more thing what if there is text field in which data is coming through session and the same form will change according to it. I mean instead of <select> there is `<input type="hidden" id="cat" value="<?php echo $value_to_change_form;?>"`

Comment: If you change your `table` ID by `<table id="<?php echo $value_to_change_form;?> style="display:none">` and replace in your javascript `if (this.value == "Others") {
                    $('#Other').show();
                } else {
                    $('#Other').hide();
                }` by `$('#'+$('#cat').val()).show()` it should work. Example here https://jsfiddle.net/fns73g9m/